# While loop in bash executes only once

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, ffmpeg

I have a file sorted_result.txt, It contains the following:

```
00:7:11.8
00:8:32.0
00:9:16.8
00:19:1.6
00:24:22.84
```

When I run the following code, the while loop executes only once instead of running for each line in the file.

```
#!/bin/bash

input="./sorted_result.txt"

count=1
initial=00:00:00
sixty=60
while read line
do
  ffmpeg -i cnbc.avi -vcodec h264 -vf fps=25 -ss $initial -to $line $count.avi
  count=$((count + 1))
  initial=$line
done < "$input"
```

Please help

Comment: shellcheck.net notes that `ffmpeg` might eat the rest of your stdin, which would prevent the loop from happening again

Comment: You can verifiy if @EricRenouf's hint is the problem by replacing `ffmpeg ...` with `echo ffmpeg ...`. If so, the fix is `ffmpeg ... < /dev/null`.

Comment: Seems to work for me…

Comment: alternately, we can read from a different file descriptor: `while read -u3 line ... 3< "$input"`

Comment: You can use the `ffmpeg` option `-nostdin` instead of `< /dev/null`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard -> your answer worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `-nostdin` between `ffmpeg` and `-i`